# Claims and Roles

Tags: authentication, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5, adfs2.0, federated-identity

I am in the process of migrating an MVC5 application from forms authentication to federated authentication.  I am using ADFS to federate my application and that is working fine.  I have groups set up in AD already and thought that when I would use this code:

```
if(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.IsInRole(@"MY-ROLE"))
```

True would be return if the AD user was in fact a member of "MY-ROLE" this doesn't appear to be the case.  Am I missing something here??  (I am new to federated services so forgive me if I have missed something obvious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a claim rule that maps groups to Roles.

Send LDAP Attribute as Claim.

Use "Token Groups - Unqualified Names" and map to Role

i.e. Rule language would be:

c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"), query = ";tokenGroups;{0}", param = c.Value);

WIF on the application side will then do the mapping to IsInRole.